# Is there a way to re-position of uv maps for stay together by each mesh automatically?

Tags: texturing, uv

I have a model, and this is the result after unwrap:
[image]

It seems fine but look at this, I selected UV of one of the wheel:
[image]

As you can see that each island located too far and it's make me really hard to painting.

If I unwrap those mesh one by one, texture scales doesn't fit at all.

Is there a way to make them stay together by each mesh automatically?